Cómo utilizar un índice en 2 tablas de mysql?
Tengo una tabla de personal en la cuál grabo la identificación y la ciudad en donde trabaja.
en esta misma tabla he creado un índice agrupado
CREATE INDEX `AK_CIUDAD` USING BTREE ON `data`.`t_personal` (`per_ciudad`, `per_id`) VISIBLE;

Las sentencias básicamente son iguales solo se diferencian por el nombre de la tabla; la primera en donde surge es la tabla t_personal y la segunda es t_personald.
CREATE INDEX `AK_CIUDAD` USING BTREE ON `data`.`t_personald` (`per_ciudad`, `per_id`) VISIBLE;

Quiero saber si en otra tabla (en la que voy a grabar más detalles) que va a estar relacionada a la tabla "personal" le puedo crear un índice con el mismo nombre y las mismas columnas que son parte del índice
en el momento de ejecutar el script me salió un mensaje de error 1061 que según mysql es duplicidad de nombre

Hola. No se entiende tu pregunta. ¿Podrías agregar los CREATE TABLE de ambas tablas y los problemas o errores que tienes?

el indice es por tabla.. por lo tanto si podria tener el mismo nombre.. pero igual, no queda claro tu problema.. probaste y tuviste un error?
